# Creating Activities to be opened

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to open activity when I side scroll in my `mainActivity`: "Like Playstore".

I have create 3 activities and I don't know how to insert to my `mainActivity`.

```
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
            /** Here I must add the code to open activity but I don't know how ;-) **/
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: please read about Intents and Intent filters in Android.

Comment: Why would you add the code immediately after a `return` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Look at

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivity

and

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)

It should clarify how you start a new activity from yours.